# mySql - find all not friends of a user

Tags: mysql

I am making a social network, and I'm trying to write a mySql query that find all the users that are not friends of a specific user.
There is one table - USERS,that has id_user,name and email.

```
USERS:
user_id , name , email..
1         Dan     a@a.com
2         Ron     b@b.com
3         James   c@c.com
4         Joe     d@d.com
5         Max     c@c.com
```

And FRIENDS table that show the relationships (status=2 mean that the two are friends):

```
FRIENDS:
user_id , friend_id , status
1             2         2
3             1         2
4             3         2
```

What is the mySql query that gives the list of the user_id(from USERS) that are not friends of user_id =1 ? (users 4 and 5).

Answer (score 2):

An anti-join pattern should be sufficient.

It looks like "a isa friend of b" can be represented in the friends table by a a row, either `(a,b,2)` or `(b,a,2)`.  (That's not entirely clear to me, but I'm going to assume that's true for now.)

This query is just a first cut. To check for friends both ways in the friends table, I'm going to use an `OR` condition in the join predicate.

This is essentially getting all rows from `users`, along with "matching" rows from `friends`.  The "trick" is the predicate in the `WHERE` clause, which eliminates all rows that found a "match" in friends, leaving only those rows from `users` that didn't have a "match".

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.name
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN friends f
    ON ( f.user_id   = u.user_id AND f.friend_id = ? AND f.status = 2 )
    OR ( f.friend_id = u.user_id AND f.user_id   = ? AND f.status = 2 )
 WHERE f.user_id   IS NULL
    OR f.friend_id IS NULL
```

Unfortunately, the MySQL optimizer doesn't usually handle these `OR` conditions too elegantly. As another cut at a re-write, we can try splitting the join to friends into two left joins.

I think this is equivalent:

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.name
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN friends f
    ON ( f.user_id   = u.user_id AND f.friend_id = ? AND f.status = 2 )
  LEFT
  JOIN friends g
    OR ( g.friend_id = u.user_id AND g.user_id   = ? AND g.status = 2 )
 WHERE f.user_id   IS NULL 
   AND g.friend_id IS NULL
```

(I haven't tested that second query... the goal is to do the same thing.  All rows from `users`, along with matching rows from `friends`, and then filter out all the rows that had a `match`.

**EDIT**

I think we'd also need to filter out the row from `users` "of a specific user". The queries above would return the user himself as "not a friend" of himself. To accomplish that, we could add to the `WHERE` clause

```
 AND u.user_id <> ?
```

For the first query, we need to take care with the order of precedence between the `OR` and `AND` boolean operators... I think we'd need to wrap the two `OR`'d conditions in the first query in parens.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

There are a couple of other query patterns that can return an equivalent result. As two examples, we can use predicates of the form `NOT IN (subquery)`, or predicates of the form `NOT EXISTS (subquery)`.

**using "NOT IN (subquery)"**

With this form, take care that the subquery does not return a NULL value. If there's a NULL value in the list, the predicate will *not* return TRUE.

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.name
  FROM users u
 WHERE u.user_id NOT IN ( SELECT f.user_id
                            FROM friends f
                           WHERE f.user_id IS NOT NULL
                             AND f.status = 2
                             AND f.friend_id = ?
                        )
   AND u.user_id NOT IN ( SELECT f.friend_id
                            FROM friends f
                           WHERE f.friend_id IS NOT NULL
                             AND f.status = 2
                             AND f.user_id = ?
                        )
   AND u.user_id <> ?
```

**using "NOT EXISTS (subquery)"**

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.name
  FROM users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM friends f
                     WHERE f.user_id = u.user_id
                       AND f.status = 2
                       AND f.friend_id = ?
                  )
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM friends g
                     WHERE g.friend_id = u.user_id
                       AND g.status = 2
                       AND g.user_id = ?
                  )
   AND u.user_id <> ?
```

Comment: @Strawberry:  I had to stop somewhere. From a "personal satisfaction" point of view, I'd prefer twice as many rows in the `friends` table,,, having both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` in that table. I could use an inline view, two queries combined with a `UNION ALL` set operator, to return that set. For "a specific user", I'd use appropriate predicates. But, we could get an equivalent result by conditionally "swapping" `a` and `b`, without a UNION ALL. I had to stop somewhere.